# deleting records from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, delete-row

Continuing with my simple CRUD, I'm stuck again...

So I have a table created called "usuaris" and a column called "id" which is my auto-increment and then another column called "usuari_nom". Now, I want to add "delete function", so when I am displaying the records of my table I've added a  to delete it:

```
 <div id="main">
        <?php 

        global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuaris";

    if($grup_usuaris = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
         echo "<table>";
         echo "<tr><th>Usuaris</th><th>Accions</th></tr>";
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($grup_usuaris)) {
                 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['usuari_nom'] . "</td><td><a href=\"elimina_usuari.php?subject=" . $row['id'] . "\">Eliminar usuari</a></td></tr>";

             }
         echo "</table>";
         echo "<a href=\"nou_usuari.php\">+ Afegeix Usuari</a>";
         mysqli_free_result($grup_usuaris);
    } else {
        echo "query failed";
        echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }                 
        ?>
    </div>
```

So now, If I click on "eliminar usuari" it goes to the file where I am adding the query to delete, plus the id of that user; for example: "http://localhost/calendario/elimina_usuari.php?subject=6". But then, in the file elimina_usuari.php, how do I select the id to know what record to delete?

I've thought with $_GET but it doesn't seems to work, either with $_POST:

### elimina_usuari.php

```
<?php 

global $conn;

$usuari_id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE id = {$usuari_id} LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 1) {
     redirect_to("calendari.php");      
} else {
echo "no eliminat";
}
?>
```

Any clue how can I get its id? Should I take it from the url somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're doing fine.

just need to change this

```
$usuari_id = $_GET['id'];
```

to

```
$usuari_id = $_GET['subject'];
```

as you're setting `subject` instead of `id` in your url

```
http://localhost/calendario/elimina_usuari.php?subject=6
                                               ^
```

and if you want to process `id`, like `$_GET['id']`, you need to change URL.

```
"http://localhost/calendario/elimina_usuari.php?id=6"
                                                ^ change here
```

**EDIT**

*as per your comment*,

you can use any `$variable` to `$_POST` or `$_GET`, it has nothing to do with the database column name.

Like you can use following.

```
"http://localhost/calendario/elimina_usuari.php?eve_mf=6"
```

and on `elimina_usuari.php` page,

```
$id = $_GET['eve_mf'];
```

and second part, *why can I do that and I don't need to call it id as it is called in my db table?*

Again, it's not the issue what you call `variables` in you local environment, all you to do(and should take care of) is to put right parameters in your `sql query`.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE id = {$usuari_id} LIMIT 1";
```

Here `id` is the name of your column name in your database. You **can't** change it here if you even want it to.

however, `$usuari_id` is your local variable, and you can change it whatever you want.

Hope I've explained what you're looking for :)

Comment: Oux! Again it happened because I| haven't paid enough attention. 

I can not accept your answer until it passes 8 minutes, I will do it in a minute :)

But.... I have a question, if I want to add "http://localhost/calendario/elimina_usuari.php?usuari_id=6"   (usuari_id), why it is still working although my column in the table is called just id? I mean.... if I do:

$usuari_id = $_GET['usuari_id'];

And then on the link to elimina_usuari.php?usuari_id   why can I do that and I don't need to call it id as it is called in my db table? Have I expressed myself right? :S

Answer (score 1):

You can get the id with `$_GET['subject']`.

Please be aware about [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) as you are wrongly get the id of the user to be deleted:

```
$usuari_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['subject']);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 

global $conn;
$usuari_id = $_GET['subject'];
$query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE id = {$usuari_id} LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 1) {
 redirect_to("calendari.php");      
} else {
echo "no eliminat";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to Get the exact variable name or parameter name which you have sent with your url

I mean see your url contains  subject=6
that means you have to get subject instead of id;

please replace this code

```
$usuari_id = $_GET['id'];
```

to

```
$usuari_id = $_GET['subject'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in elimina_usurai.php

```
<?php 

global $conn;

$usuari_id = $_GET['subject'];
$query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE id = {$usuari_id} LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 1) {
     redirect_to("calendari.php");      
} else {
echo "no eliminat";
}
?>
```